# what's wrong with this sql query?

Tags: sql-server

```
UPDATE UserListColumnData 
set  UserListColumnValue = (case when Contains(ProductDetailObjects.InnerText, **ProductDetailObjects**.AdminInnerText) then 
'Condition True'Else 'Condition False' End)
FROM         VariableDataObjectMaping INNER JOIN  
                      UserListColumnData ON VariableDataObjectMaping.UserListColumnID = UserListColumnData.UserListColumnID INNER JOIN                    
                      UserListColumns ON UserListColumnData.UserListColumnID=UserListColumns.UserListColumnID INNER JOIN                       
                      ProductDetailObjects ON VariableDataObjectMaping.ObjectId = ProductDetailObjects.ObjectID INNER JOIN  
                      ProductDetail ON ProductDetailObjects.ProductDetailID = ProductDetail.ProductDetailID INNER JOIN  
                      Products ON ProductDetail.ProductID = Products.ProductID  
WHERE     (Products.ProductID = 275)
```

giving following error after compile.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'ProductDetailObjects'.
```

but when i write any string in contain function it works like.

```
UPDATE UserListColumnData 
set  UserListColumnValue = (case when Contains(ProductDetailObjects.InnerText, 'aab') then 
'Condition True'Else 'Condition False' End)
FROM         VariableDataObjectMaping INNER JOIN  
                      UserListColumnData ON VariableDataObjectMaping.UserListColumnID = UserListColumnData.UserListColumnID INNER JOIN                    
                      UserListColumns ON UserListColumnData.UserListColumnID=UserListColumns.UserListColumnID INNER JOIN                       
                      ProductDetailObjects ON VariableDataObjectMaping.ObjectId = ProductDetailObjects.ObjectID INNER JOIN  
                      ProductDetail ON ProductDetailObjects.ProductDetailID = ProductDetail.ProductDetailID INNER JOIN  
                      Products ON ProductDetail.ProductID = Products.ProductID  
WHERE     (Products.ProductID = 275)
```

why it is not working with string column name (ProductDetailObjects.AdminInnerText????)

Comment: Why are there asterisks around the table name, ProductDetailObjects.AdminInnerText?

Comment: i mentioned myself because that's the point the query compile gives the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add space before ELSE

```
'Condition True'Else
```

EDIT:

Update it like this:

```cs
CASE 
      WHEN ProductDetailObjects.InnerText 
      LIKE '%' + ProductDetailObjects.AdminInnerText + '%'       
      THEN  'Condition True'
      ELSE 'Condition False' 
END
```

Comment: its not a space problem. When i replace ProductDetailObject.AdminInnerText with some string then its work otherwise its give an error.

Answer (score 4):

You can only use a constant as a search query in `CONTAINS`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this:

```
'Condition True'Else 'Condition False' End)
                ^--- missing a space here
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a field name as the 2nd argument of `CONTAINS`, only a literal string or variable; its designed to look for a specific search clause across all values of the column(s) in its first argument.

Comment: what do the search clauses look like, do they have to be FTS clauses?